# Python, how to insert value in Powerpoint template?

Tags: python, powerpoint

I want to use an existing powerpoint presentation to generate a series of reports:

In my imagination the powerpoint slides will have content in such or similar form:

```
Date of report: {{report_date}} 
Number of Sales: {{no_sales}}
...
```

Then my python app opens the powerpoint, fills in the values for this report and saves the report with a new name.
I googled, but could not find a solution for this.

There is python-pptx out there, but this is all about creating a new presentation and not inserting values in a template.

Can anybody advice?

Comment: You can write to a .tex file using standard I/O. Are you set on using powerpoint or can you use a beamer presentation?

Comment: "python-pptx allows you to create new presentations as well as make changes to existing ones" - isn't that what you're looking for? making changes to existing ones?

Comment: Well, I read that, but the documentation only describes how to create content, not how to find an element and change the text. I also could not find a single example using google.

Comment: @user2241910:  I have received the report template in pptx and it is carefully designed and I dont want to transfer to another format

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, barring some other library which has additional functionality, you need some sort of brute force approach to iterate the Slides collection and each Slide's respective Shapes collection in order to identify the matching shape (unless there is some other library which has additional "Find" functionality in PPT).  Here is brute force using only `win32com`:

```
from win32com import client

find_date = r'{{report_date}}'
find_sales = r'{{no_sales}}'
report_date = '01/01/2016' # Modify as needed
no_sales = '604'           # Modify as needed

path = 'c:/path/to/file.pptx'
outpath = 'c:/path/to/output.pptx'
ppt = client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
pres = ppt.Presentations.Open(path, WithWindow=False)
for sld in pres.Slides:
    for shp in sld.Shapes:
        with shp.TextFrame.TextRange as tr:
            if find_date in tr.Text
                tr.Replace(find_date, report_date)
            elif find_sales in shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
                tr.Replace(find_sales, no_sales)
pres.SaveAs(outpath)
pres.Close()
ppt.Quit()
```

If these strings are inside other strings with *mixed* text formatting, it gets trickier to preserve existing formatting, but it should still be possible.

If the template file is still in design and subject to your control, I would consider giving the shape a unique identifier like a `CustomXMLPart` or you could assign something to the shapes' `AlternativeText` property. The latter is easier to work with because it doesn't require well-formed XML, and also because it's able to be seen & manipulated via the native UI, whereas the `CustomXMLPart` is only accessible programmatically, and even that is kind of counterintuitive. You'll still need to do shape-by-shape iteration, but you can avoid the string comparisons just by checking the relevant property value.

Comment: Hello! This is a very neat example for basic use. Can you tell where did you find supporting material (help, guide, tutorials, etc.) for the PPT commands where the code and its use like ```PowerPoint.Presentations.Open()```, or ```Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox()``` are explained? Maybe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint/object-model?

Comment: ^^^^ Indeed, this is the right answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a ".ppx" file I had hanging around.
A microsoft office power point ".pptx" file is in ".zip" format.
When I unzipped my file, I got an ".xml" file and three directories.
My ".pptx" file has 116 slides comprised of 3,477 files and 22 directories/subdirectories.
Normally, I would say it is not workable, but since you have only two short changes you probably could figure out what to change and zip the files to make a new ".ppx" file.
A warning: there are some xml blobs of binary data in one or more of the ".xml" files.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do what you want with python-pptx, just perhaps not as straightforwardly as you imagine.

You can read the objects in a presentation, including the slides and the shapes on the slides. So if you wanted to change the text of the second shape on the second slide, you could do it like this:

```
slide = prs.slides[1]
shape = slide.shapes[1]
shape.text = 'foobar'
```

The only real question is how you find the shape you're interested in. If you can make non-visual changes to the presentation (template), you can determine the shape id or shape name and use that. Or you could fetch the text for each shape and use regular expressions to find your keyword/replacement bits.

It's not without its challenges, and python-pptx doesn't have features specifically designed for this role, but based on the parameters of your question, this is definitely a doable thing.